# Normality and Commutator

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I've been thinking of this problem for quite sometime. Is this valid or there should be a certain condition for G?

**Let G be a group. If H is a subgroup of G'. Then H is normal in G.**

G' means commutator or derived

Comment: I guess if $G'$ is a subset of $H$, then $H$ is normal in $G$.

Answer (score 1):

For the alternating group on 5 letters, $A_5$, then $A_5=A_5'$ and $A_5$ is simple, but $A_5$ has proper cyclic subgroups $H$ which are not normal by simplicity.